# OLEDB Update Query fails to update .xlsm file

Tags: excel, vba, oledb

i'm trying to update an already open macro file (.xlsm) using update Query. the Update Query updates the the macro sheet sometimes but misses to update the sheet in some cases where there is no error appearing in this case.

My connection strig:

```
connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbpath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES"";"
```

Update Query:

> strSQL = "UPDATE [" & QuerySheet & "] SET [Alias]= '" & Alias &
>   "',[Tolerable Error]= '" & TE & "', [Account Type]= '" &
>   AccountTypeList & "',[Account Sub-Type]= '" & AccountSubTypeList &
>   "',[Account Class]= '" & AccountClassCheckbox & "' ,[Account
>   Sub-Class]= '" & AccountSubClassCheckbox & "',[GL Accounts]= '" &
>   GLAccountsCheckbox & "',[Scoping Dropdown Selection]= '" &
>   ComboBoxSelectedValue & "',[Account Type (ALL)]='" & AccountTypeList &
>   "',[Account Sub-type (ALL)]='" & AccountSubTypeList & "',[Account
>   Class (ALL)]='" & AccountClassList & "',[Account Sub-class (ALL)]='" &
>   AccountSubClassList & "',[GL Accounts (ALL)]='" & GLAccountList & "'
>   Where [Category Name]= '" & PrimaryStatement & "' AND [Group]='" &
>   GroupCounter & "'"

```
 strSQL = "UPDATE [" & QuerySheet & "] SET [Alias]= '" & Alias & "',[Tolerable Error]= '" & TE & "', [Account Type]= '" & AccountTypeList & "',[Account Sub-Type]= '" & AccountSubTypeList & "',[Account Class]= '" & AccountClassCheckbox & "' ,[Account Sub-Class]= '" & AccountSubClassCheckbox & "',[GL Accounts]= '" & GLAccountsCheckbox & "',[Scoping Dropdown Selection]= '" & ComboBoxSelectedValue & "',[Account Type (ALL)]='" & AccountTypeList & "',[Account Sub-type (ALL)]='" & AccountSubTypeList & "',[Account Class (ALL)]='" & AccountClassList & "',[Account Sub-class (ALL)]='" & AccountSubClassList & "',[GL Accounts (ALL)]='" & GLAccountList & "' Where [Category Name]= '" & PrimaryStatement & "' AND [Group]='" & GroupCounter & "'"
```

Comment: Are you certain the query is the issue? Some of the surrounding code may help as there is not a lot of information here.

Comment: Query don't have any issue, it updates sheets , but sometimes not. if it fails to update the sheet i don't get any error message either..wonder whats the issue